# Is there an API available for the Youtube "stream now (beta)" service?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I recently found a new service on Youtube located at ["stream now"](http://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard). It appears to still be in Beta

I would like to interact with this service using the Youtube Data API. To be more specific I would like to get the streaming address (after oauth authorization).

But the problem is I can't find it in the [Youtube APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no endpoint available for this particular function (yet). As an alternative, you can create a new live event using  [youtube.liveStreams.insert](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.liveStreams.insert) and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you can query the "Stream now" stream, and it returns a LiveBroadcast object the same as any other stream.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329439) to find the "Stream now" stream you call [`LiveBroadcasts.List`](http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) with `broadcastType=persistent` and `mine=true`.

You can check the [`liveBroadcast.status.lifeCycleStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.lifeCycleStatus) to determine whether the "Stream now" stream is live.