# How to get stream name/key of YouTube Live "Stream Now" service

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

YouTube added "Stream now (beta)" service last July which makes live streaming much easier.

Using Youtube verified programs like "XSplit Broadcaster" you can stream to "Stream now" after authorization.

I'm also doing a streaming application and what I'm looking for is the API to get the stream name of the default "Stream now" stream. With the stream name I can stream content to YouTube.

YouTube documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/ doesn't mention anything about it, and the default broadcast is not included in the result of youtube.liveBroadcasts.list.

If XSplit Broadcaster can do it, I think there must have an API for it. Anyone knows it?

====================================
Update:

Form the documentation here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts
there should be a isDefault field in a Broadcast (snippet.isDefaultBroadcast). And there should be a default broadcast and default live stream.

But when I ran livebroadcasts.list to get all broadcasts, I got

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse",
 "etag": "\"abQHWywil_AkNqdqji7_FqiK-u4/z2Ncj_KliOCAGV1jEVPYCsHbZn0\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 4,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

Although the totalResults = 4, there's nothing in returned items.

Comment: What happens if you try to just list all live broadcasts for yourself using `liveBroadcasts/list` and setting `mine=true`?

Comment: Hi JAL, the result I pasted in the original post was just what I got after running GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=+id +snippet + contentDetails + status & mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: What about `liveStreams/list`?  Can you verify that the the event was actually live in the web interface?  https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events

Comment: Hi JAL, liveStreams/list also returns 0. Please note that what I want to get is the stream name of "Stream Now" which is always there. It's different from what you created in the Events section. Now I've deleted every event under events. I suppose I should get a broadcast/live whose isDefaultBroadcast/isDefaultStream is true, but could't. If you have Youtube live enabled, you can easily try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved, the default broadcast can be retrieved by setting broadcastType to "persistent" in livebrocasts.list.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=+id%2C+snippet%2C+contentDetails%2C+status&broadcastType=persistent&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And default stream can be retrieved by livestreams.list with boundstreamid.

Comment: Very nice! You did a lot of fiddling it seems. I was at it for the last 3 days... But: does the URI above work without OAuth? I tried it with a server API key, and it returns "401 - Login required". First I thought it is because of the mine=true parameter. But it seemed to work with you. Do I do something wrong?

Comment: But in some cases, i haven't get any boundStreamId when i pass broadcastType to "persistent" . How can i fix this?