# YouTube completed LiveBroadcasts doesn't include "Stream now" broadcasts

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

YouTube allows for two methods of live streaming: `Stream now` and `Events`.  When using the API to retrieve completed broadcasts it only returns broadcasts that were streamed via `Events`, not broadcasts that were streamed via `Stream Now`.

This is easily viewed via the interactive API pages:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list
(`part` = `snippet` and `broadcastStatus` = `completed`)
Provided of course that your youtube channel has performed both types of broadcasts.

At the moment I am resorting to retrieving all [`PlaylistItems`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) in my upload list, but by doing this I lose the `snippet.actualStartTime` and can only use the `snippet.publishedAt` field, which is highly misleading for a broadcast that was scheduled days/weeks in advance.

Is there a way to correctly retrieve completed `Stream now` broadcasts?  Or am I misunderstanding something?  To further compound my confusion, inside the YouTube Creator Studio under Live Streaming -> Events, if I switch the view to show Completed events, it shows both category of videos.

Comment: I think it is a problem within the API itself. So maybe only a googler can answer this question. I cannot find any clue to do this in the API. 
Try to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144186) if it can help and give you any idea.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi, but that question is different and doesn't help in my scenario.